# AJAX call returns web page source

Tags: ajax, jquery, servlets, websphere-portal

I'm making a GET request to a servlet through jQuery AJAX. In the servlet I'm using `httpResponse.sendRedirect("abc.com")`. In my AJAX call, the source of that webpage (abc.com) is being returned instead of the servlet redirecting me to that page.

Further info: I'm running all this on Websphere Portal Server 6.1 and am taking care of CORS using an IBM proxy servlet.

My question is this: how do I, from the servlet, redirect to the requested URI. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do redirection after ajax call completes(on success) using window.location.href . just return httpresponse in your function instead of redirection.

Comment: Yeah, i returned the URL from the servlet and opened it through javascript. Set the dataType to html also, so that worked. Thanks.